# Problem with meta_value order after update

Tags: order, meta-value

I use following array and works fine... 
sort post by meta_key where value of t_count is a number:

```
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => 10,
 'meta_key' => 't_count',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   );
      query_posts($args);
```

I use 3.4.2 but if I upgrade to 3.5 array above do not sort correctly.

I've try also meta_value_num but do not works fine.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()`

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'meta_key' => 't_count',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC'
 );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

// Restore original Query & Post Data
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Above code should work!

Comment: Thanks @Furqan but do not works.
Example meta_value array stored
a:2:{s:5:"count";d:31714;s:7:"timeout";i:1358206247;}

Comment: are you using "WPAlchemy MetaBox PHP Class" ?

Comment: No, I use:
       
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 't_count', $meta );

Comment: yes! 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' is only work with single value not with serialized array.
i think you have to hack this but i have no idea about this.

another solution is

have a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i6nOSVOBaY 

use wpalchemy-metabox (http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)